# How to select a file through a GUI in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I want to create a GUI such that an image file should get copied to the matlab workspace on clicking a button titled "selct image". It should prompt me to select a particular image from a given folder, then on clicking a button titled "Run", an m file (which I have written) should be run and display the output.

Can anyone help me in this regard?

Answer (score 6):

Have a look at this:

http://www.mathworks.de/help/techdoc/ref/uigetfile.html

Creating GUIs in MATLAB is pretty straightforward. Type "guide" in the command line, graphically add your buttons, then fill the callback functions of those buttons with the code you need.

Answer (score 3):

The entire answer might be a little long, but let`s try anyway

as previous posters recommended, use `guide` command to start designing a GUI.
Add some buttons. Right click on a button will provide you with a "button callback function", which is called whenever you press a button on a running GUI.

The important commands are:

### BUTTON1: Read an image through a modal dialog in a GUI in Matlab

and put the image data into the variables X and map in base workspace

```
% --- Executes on button press in pushbutton1.
function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
disp('Load image button pressed ...')
%% Create a file dialog for images
[filename, user_cancelled] = imgetfile;
    if user_cancelled
            disp('User pressed cancel')
    else
            disp(['User selected ', filename])
    end

    %% Read the selected image into the variable
    disp('Reading the image into variable X');
    [X,map] = imread(filename);
    %% Copy X and map to base workspace, overwriting the content !!!
    assignin('base','X',X); 
    assignin('base','map',map); 
    %% Now you have X and map variables in the base workspace
```

### BUTTON2: Run a custom command

do something on the X and map variables in the base workspace

```
% --- Executes on button press in pushbutton2.
function pushbutton2_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushbutton2 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

%% Put your own code here to be called
disp('Run button pressed ...')
evalin('base', 'if exist(''X'', ''var''), disp(''image loaded into X''), else, disp(''image not loaded yet''), end');
% if exist('X', 'var'), disp('image loaded into X'), else, disp('image not loaded yet'), end)
```

### Alternatively, you can create your own file dialogs in matlab:

```
%% Alternatively use the following for reading image files of your own choosing
[filename, pathname] = uigetfile({'*.jpg;*.png;*.gif;*.bmp', 'All Image Files (*.jpg, *.png, *.gif, *.bmp)'; ...
                '*.*',                   'All Files (*.*)'}, ...
                'Pick an image file');

%This code checks if the user pressed cancel on the dialog.
        if isequal(filename,0) || isequal(pathname,0)
             disp('User pressed cancel')
        else
             disp(['User selected ', fullfile(pathname, filename)])

        end
```

Here is the entire file working, just copy&paste:

```
    function varargout = guitutorial_export(varargin)
    % GUITUTORIAL_EXPORT M-file for guitutorial_export.fig
    %      GUITUTORIAL_EXPORT, by itself, creates a new GUITUTORIAL_EXPORT or raises the existing
    %      singleton*.
    %
    %      H = GUITUTORIAL_EXPORT returns the handle to a new GUITUTORIAL_EXPORT or the handle to
    %      the existing singleton*.
    %
    %      GUITUTORIAL_EXPORT('CALLBACK',hObject,eventData,handles,...) calls the local
    %      function named CALLBACK in GUITUTORIAL_EXPORT.M with the given input arguments.
    %
    %      GUITUTORIAL_EXPORT('Property','Value',...) creates a new GUITUTORIAL_EXPORT or raises the
    %      existing singleton*.  Starting from the left, property value pairs are
    %      applied to the GUI before guitutorial_export_OpeningFcn gets called.  An
    %      unrecognized property name or invalid value makes property application
    %      stop.  All inputs are passed to guitutorial_export_OpeningFcn via varargin.
    %
    %      *See GUI Options on GUIDE's Tools menu.  Choose "GUI allows only one
    %      instance to run (singleton)".
    %
    % See also: GUIDE, GUIDATA, GUIHANDLES

    % Edit the above text to modify the response to help guitutorial_export

    % Last Modified by GUIDE v2.5 01-Apr-2012 00:26:11

    % Begin initialization code - DO NOT EDIT
    gui_Singleton = 1;
    gui_State = struct('gui_Name',       mfilename, ...
                                         'gui_Singleton',  gui_Singleton, ...
                                         'gui_OpeningFcn', @guitutorial_export_OpeningFcn, ...
                                         'gui_OutputFcn',  @guitutorial_export_OutputFcn, ...
                                         'gui_LayoutFcn',  @guitutorial_export_LayoutFcn, ...
                                         'gui_Callback',   []);
    if nargin && ischar(varargin{1})
            gui_State.gui_Callback = str2func(varargin{1});
    end

    if nargout
            [varargout{1:nargout}] = gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
    else
            gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
    end
    % End initialization code - DO NOT EDIT


    % --- Executes just before guitutorial_export is made visible.
    function guitutorial_export_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)
    % This function has no output args, see OutputFcn.
    % hObject    handle to figure
    % eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
    % handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
    % varargin   command line arguments to guitutorial_export (see VARARGIN)

    % Choose default command line output for guitutorial_export
    handles.output = hObject;

    % Update handles structure
    guidata(hObject, handles);

    % UIWAIT makes guitutorial_export wait for user response (see UIRESUME)
    % uiwait(handles.figure1);


    % --- Outputs from this function are returned to the command line.
    function varargout = guitutorial_export_OutputFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles) 
    % varargout  cell array for returning output args (see VARARGOUT);
    % hObject    handle to figure
    % eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
    % handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

    % Get default command line output from handles structure
    varargout{1} = handles.output;


    % --- Executes on button press in pushbutton1.
    function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
    % hObject    handle to pushbutton1 (see GCBO)
    % eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
    % handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

    disp('Load image button pressed ...')

    %% Alternatively use the following for reading image files of your own choosing
    % [filename, pathname] = uigetfile({'*.jpg;*.png;*.gif;*.bmp', 'All Image Files (*.jpg, *.png, *.gif, *.bmp)'; ...
    %         '*.*',                   'All Files (*.*)'}, ...
    %         'Pick an image file');
    %       
    % %This code checks if the user pressed cancel on the dialog.
    %     if isequal(filename,0) || isequal(pathname,0)
    %        disp('User pressed cancel')
    %     else
    %        disp(['User selected ', fullfile(pathname, filename)])
    %            
    %       end

    [filename, user_cancelled] = imgetfile;
            if user_cancelled
                    disp('User pressed cancel')
            else
                    disp(['User selected ', filename])
            end

    %% Read the selected image into the variable
    disp('Reading the image into variable X');
    [X,map] = imread(filename);
    %% Copy X and map to base workspace, overwriting the content !!!
    assignin('base','X',X); 
    assignin('base','map',map); 
    %% 


    % --- Executes on button press in pushbutton2.
    function pushbutton2_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
    % hObject    handle to pushbutton2 (see GCBO)
    % eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
    % handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

    %% Put your own code here to be called
    disp('Run button pressed ...')
    evalin('base', 'if exist(''X'', ''var''), disp(''image loaded into X''), else, disp(''image not loaded yet''), end');
    % if exist('X', 'var'), disp('image loaded into X'), else, disp('image not loaded yet'), end)



    % --- Creates and returns a handle to the GUI figure. 
    function h1 = guitutorial_export_LayoutFcn(policy)
    % policy - create a new figure or use a singleton. 'new' or 'reuse'.

    persistent hsingleton;
    if strcmpi(policy, 'reuse') & ishandle(hsingleton)
            h1 = hsingleton;
            return;
    end

    appdata = [];
    appdata.GUIDEOptions = struct(...
            'active_h', [], ...
            'taginfo', struct(...
            'figure', 2, ...
            'pushbutton', 3), ...
            'override', 0, ...
            'release', 13, ...
            'resize', 'none', ...
            'accessibility', 'callback', ...
            'mfile', 1, ...
            'callbacks', 1, ...
            'singleton', 1, ...
            'syscolorfig', 1, ...
            'blocking', 0, ...
            'lastSavedFile', '/home/mosi/Documents/MATLAB/guitutorial_export.m', ...
            'lastFilename', '/home/mosi/Documents/MATLAB/guitutorial.fig');
    appdata.lastValidTag = 'figure1';
    appdata.GUIDELayoutEditor = [];
    appdata.initTags = struct(...
            'handle', [], ...
            'tag', 'figure1');

    h1 = figure(...
    'Units','characters',...
    'Color',[0.701960784313725 0.701960784313725 0.701960784313725],...
    'Colormap',[0 0 0.5625;0 0 0.625;0 0 0.6875;0 0 0.75;0 0 0.8125;0 0 0.875;0 0 0.9375;0 0 1;0 0.0625 1;0 0.125 1;0 0.1875 1;0 0.25 1;0 0.3125 1;0 0.375 1;0 0.4375 1;0 0.5 1;0 0.5625 1;0 0.625 1;0 0.6875 1;0 0.75 1;0 0.8125 1;0 0.875 1;0 0.9375 1;0 1 1;0.0625 1 1;0.125 1 0.9375;0.1875 1 0.875;0.25 1 0.8125;0.3125 1 0.75;0.375 1 0.6875;0.4375 1 0.625;0.5 1 0.5625;0.5625 1 0.5;0.625 1 0.4375;0.6875 1 0.375;0.75 1 0.3125;0.8125 1 0.25;0.875 1 0.1875;0.9375 1 0.125;1 1 0.0625;1 1 0;1 0.9375 0;1 0.875 0;1 0.8125 0;1 0.75 0;1 0.6875 0;1 0.625 0;1 0.5625 0;1 0.5 0;1 0.4375 0;1 0.375 0;1 0.3125 0;1 0.25 0;1 0.1875 0;1 0.125 0;1 0.0625 0;1 0 0;0.9375 0 0;0.875 0 0;0.8125 0 0;0.75 0 0;0.6875 0 0;0.625 0 0;0.5625 0 0],...
    'IntegerHandle','off',...
    'InvertHardcopy',get(0,'defaultfigureInvertHardcopy'),...
    'MenuBar','none',...
    'Name','guitutorial',...
    'NumberTitle','off',...
    'PaperPosition',get(0,'defaultfigurePaperPosition'),...
    'Position',[103.833333333333 29.1333333333333 112 32.3333333333333],...
    'Resize','off',...
    'HandleVisibility','callback',...
    'Tag','figure1',...
    'UserData',[],...
    'Visible','on',...
    'CreateFcn', {@local_CreateFcn, blanks(0), appdata} );

    appdata = [];
    appdata.lastValidTag = 'pushbutton1';

    h2 = uicontrol(...
    'Parent',h1,...
    'Units','characters',...
    'Callback',@(hObject,eventdata)guitutorial_export('pushbutton1_Callback',hObject,eventdata,guidata(hObject)),...
    'Position',[8.16666666666667 27.5333333333333 25.1666666666667 1.4],...
    'String','Select image',...
    'Tag','pushbutton1',...
    'CreateFcn', {@local_CreateFcn, blanks(0), appdata} );

    appdata = [];
    appdata.lastValidTag = 'pushbutton2';

    h3 = uicontrol(...
    'Parent',h1,...
    'Units','characters',...
    'Callback',@(hObject,eventdata)guitutorial_export('pushbutton2_Callback',hObject,eventdata,guidata(hObject)),...
    'Position',[8.16666666666667 24.8 11.6666666666667 1.4],...
    'String','Run',...
    'Tag','pushbutton2',...
    'CreateFcn', {@local_CreateFcn, blanks(0), appdata} );


    hsingleton = h1;


    % --- Set application data first then calling the CreateFcn. 
    function local_CreateFcn(hObject, eventdata, createfcn, appdata)

    if ~isempty(appdata)
         names = fieldnames(appdata);
         for i=1:length(names)
                 name = char(names(i));
                 setappdata(hObject, name, getfield(appdata,name));
         end
    end

    if ~isempty(createfcn)
         if isa(createfcn,'function_handle')
                 createfcn(hObject, eventdata);
         else
                 eval(createfcn);
         end
    end


    % --- Handles default GUIDE GUI creation and callback dispatch
    function varargout = gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin)

    gui_StateFields =  {'gui_Name'
            'gui_Singleton'
            'gui_OpeningFcn'
            'gui_OutputFcn'
            'gui_LayoutFcn'
            'gui_Callback'};
    gui_Mfile = '';
    for i=1:length(gui_StateFields)
            if ~isfield(gui_State, gui_StateFields{i})
                    error('MATLAB:gui_mainfcn:FieldNotFound', 'Could not find field %s in the gui_State struct in GUI M-file %s', gui_StateFields{i}, gui_Mfile);
            elseif isequal(gui_StateFields{i}, 'gui_Name')
                    gui_Mfile = [gui_State.(gui_StateFields{i}), '.m'];
            end
    end

    numargin = length(varargin);

    if numargin == 0
            % GUITUTORIAL_EXPORT
            % create the GUI only if we are not in the process of loading it
            % already
            gui_Create = true;
    elseif local_isInvokeActiveXCallback(gui_State, varargin{:})
            % GUITUTORIAL_EXPORT(ACTIVEX,...)
            vin{1} = gui_State.gui_Name;
            vin{2} = [get(varargin{1}.Peer, 'Tag'), '_', varargin{end}];
            vin{3} = varargin{1};
            vin{4} = varargin{end-1};
            vin{5} = guidata(varargin{1}.Peer);
            feval(vin{:});
            return;
    elseif local_isInvokeHGCallback(gui_State, varargin{:})
            % GUITUTORIAL_EXPORT('CALLBACK',hObject,eventData,handles,...)
            gui_Create = false;
    else
            % GUITUTORIAL_EXPORT(...)
            % create the GUI and hand varargin to the openingfcn
            gui_Create = true;
    end

    if ~gui_Create
            % In design time, we need to mark all components possibly created in
            % the coming callback evaluation as non-serializable. This way, they
            % will not be brought into GUIDE and not be saved in the figure file
            % when running/saving the GUI from GUIDE.
            designEval = false;
            if (numargin>1 && ishghandle(varargin{2}))
                    fig = varargin{2};
                    while ~isempty(fig) && ~isa(handle(fig),'figure')
                            fig = get(fig,'parent');
                    end

                    designEval = isappdata(0,'CreatingGUIDEFigure') || isprop(fig,'__GUIDEFigure');
            end

            if designEval
                    beforeChildren = findall(fig);
            end

            % evaluate the callback now
            varargin{1} = gui_State.gui_Callback;
            if nargout
                    [varargout{1:nargout}] = feval(varargin{:});
            else       
                    feval(varargin{:});
            end

            % Set serializable of objects created in the above callback to off in
            % design time. Need to check whether figure handle is still valid in
            % case the figure is deleted during the callback dispatching.
            if designEval && ishandle(fig)
                    set(setdiff(findall(fig),beforeChildren), 'Serializable','off');
            end
    else
            if gui_State.gui_Singleton
                    gui_SingletonOpt = 'reuse';
            else
                    gui_SingletonOpt = 'new';
            end

            % Check user passing 'visible' P/V pair first so that its value can be
            % used by oepnfig to prevent flickering
            gui_Visible = 'auto';
            gui_VisibleInput = '';
            for index=1:2:length(varargin)
                    if length(varargin) == index || ~ischar(varargin{index})
                            break;
                    end

                    % Recognize 'visible' P/V pair
                    len1 = min(length('visible'),length(varargin{index}));
                    len2 = min(length('off'),length(varargin{index+1}));
                    if ischar(varargin{index+1}) && strncmpi(varargin{index},'visible',len1) && len2 > 1
                            if strncmpi(varargin{index+1},'off',len2)
                                    gui_Visible = 'invisible';
                                    gui_VisibleInput = 'off';
                            elseif strncmpi(varargin{index+1},'on',len2)
                                    gui_Visible = 'visible';
                                    gui_VisibleInput = 'on';
                            end
                    end
            end

            % Open fig file with stored settings.  Note: This executes all component
            % specific CreateFunctions with an empty HANDLES structure.


            % Do feval on layout code in m-file if it exists
            gui_Exported = ~isempty(gui_State.gui_LayoutFcn);
            % this application data is used to indicate the running mode of a GUIDE
            % GUI to distinguish it from the design mode of the GUI in GUIDE. it is
            % only used by actxproxy at this time.   
            setappdata(0,genvarname(['OpenGuiWhenRunning_', gui_State.gui_Name]),1);
            if gui_Exported
                    gui_hFigure = feval(gui_State.gui_LayoutFcn, gui_SingletonOpt);

                    % make figure invisible here so that the visibility of figure is
                    % consistent in OpeningFcn in the exported GUI case
                    if isempty(gui_VisibleInput)
                            gui_VisibleInput = get(gui_hFigure,'Visible');
                    end
                    set(gui_hFigure,'Visible','off')

                    % openfig (called by local_openfig below) does this for guis without
                    % the LayoutFcn. Be sure to do it here so guis show up on screen.
                    movegui(gui_hFigure,'onscreen');
            else
                    gui_hFigure = local_openfig(gui_State.gui_Name, gui_SingletonOpt, gui_Visible);
                    % If the figure has InGUIInitialization it was not completely created
                    % on the last pass.  Delete this handle and try again.
                    if isappdata(gui_hFigure, 'InGUIInitialization')
                            delete(gui_hFigure);
                            gui_hFigure = local_openfig(gui_State.gui_Name, gui_SingletonOpt, gui_Visible);
                    end
            end
            if isappdata(0, genvarname(['OpenGuiWhenRunning_', gui_State.gui_Name]))
                    rmappdata(0,genvarname(['OpenGuiWhenRunning_', gui_State.gui_Name]));
            end

            % Set flag to indicate starting GUI initialization
            setappdata(gui_hFigure,'InGUIInitialization',1);

            % Fetch GUIDE Application options
            gui_Options = getappdata(gui_hFigure,'GUIDEOptions');
            % Singleton setting in the GUI M-file takes priority if different
            gui_Options.singleton = gui_State.gui_Singleton;

            if ~isappdata(gui_hFigure,'GUIOnScreen')
                    % Adjust background color
                    if gui_Options.syscolorfig
                            set(gui_hFigure,'Color', get(0,'DefaultUicontrolBackgroundColor'));
                    end

                    % Generate HANDLES structure and store with GUIDATA. If there is
                    % user set GUI data already, keep that also.
                    data = guidata(gui_hFigure);
                    handles = guihandles(gui_hFigure);
                    if ~isempty(handles)
                            if isempty(data)
                                    data = handles;
                            else
                                    names = fieldnames(handles);
                                    for k=1:length(names)
                                            data.(char(names(k)))=handles.(char(names(k)));
                                    end
                            end
                    end
                    guidata(gui_hFigure, data);
            end

            % Apply input P/V pairs other than 'visible'
            for index=1:2:length(varargin)
                    if length(varargin) == index || ~ischar(varargin{index})
                            break;
                    end

                    len1 = min(length('visible'),length(varargin{index}));
                    if ~strncmpi(varargin{index},'visible',len1)
                            try set(gui_hFigure, varargin{index}, varargin{index+1}), catch break, end
                    end
            end

            % If handle visibility is set to 'callback', turn it on until finished
            % with OpeningFcn
            gui_HandleVisibility = get(gui_hFigure,'HandleVisibility');
            if strcmp(gui_HandleVisibility, 'callback')
                    set(gui_hFigure,'HandleVisibility', 'on');
            end

            feval(gui_State.gui_OpeningFcn, gui_hFigure, [], guidata(gui_hFigure), varargin{:});

            if isscalar(gui_hFigure) && ishandle(gui_hFigure)
                    % Handle the default callbacks of predefined toolbar tools in this
                    % GUI, if any
                    guidemfile('restoreToolbarToolPredefinedCallback',gui_hFigure); 

                    % Update handle visibility
                    set(gui_hFigure,'HandleVisibility', gui_HandleVisibility);

                    % Call openfig again to pick up the saved visibility or apply the
                    % one passed in from the P/V pairs
                    if ~gui_Exported
                            gui_hFigure = local_openfig(gui_State.gui_Name, 'reuse',gui_Visible);
                    elseif ~isempty(gui_VisibleInput)
                            set(gui_hFigure,'Visible',gui_VisibleInput);
                    end
                    if strcmpi(get(gui_hFigure, 'Visible'), 'on')
                            figure(gui_hFigure);

                            if gui_Options.singleton
                                    setappdata(gui_hFigure,'GUIOnScreen', 1);
                            end
                    end

                    % Done with GUI initialization
                    if isappdata(gui_hFigure,'InGUIInitialization')
                            rmappdata(gui_hFigure,'InGUIInitialization');
                    end

                    % If handle visibility is set to 'callback', turn it on until
                    % finished with OutputFcn
                    gui_HandleVisibility = get(gui_hFigure,'HandleVisibility');
                    if strcmp(gui_HandleVisibility, 'callback')
                            set(gui_hFigure,'HandleVisibility', 'on');
                    end
                    gui_Handles = guidata(gui_hFigure);
            else
                    gui_Handles = [];
            end

            if nargout
                    [varargout{1:nargout}] = feval(gui_State.gui_OutputFcn, gui_hFigure, [], gui_Handles);
            else
                    feval(gui_State.gui_OutputFcn, gui_hFigure, [], gui_Handles);
            end

            if isscalar(gui_hFigure) && ishandle(gui_hFigure)
                    set(gui_hFigure,'HandleVisibility', gui_HandleVisibility);
            end
    end

    function gui_hFigure = local_openfig(name, singleton, visible)

    % openfig with three arguments was new from R13. Try to call that first, if
    % failed, try the old openfig.
    if nargin('openfig') == 2
            % OPENFIG did not accept 3rd input argument until R13,
            % toggle default figure visible to prevent the figure
            % from showing up too soon.
            gui_OldDefaultVisible = get(0,'defaultFigureVisible');
            set(0,'defaultFigureVisible','off');
            gui_hFigure = openfig(name, singleton);
            set(0,'defaultFigureVisible',gui_OldDefaultVisible);
    else
            gui_hFigure = openfig(name, singleton, visible);
    end

    function result = local_isInvokeActiveXCallback(gui_State, varargin)

    try
            result = ispc && iscom(varargin{1}) ...
                             && isequal(varargin{1},gcbo);
    catch
            result = false;
    end

    function result = local_isInvokeHGCallback(gui_State, varargin)

    try
            fhandle = functions(gui_State.gui_Callback);
            result = ~isempty(findstr(gui_State.gui_Name,fhandle.file)) || ...
                             (ischar(varargin{1}) ...
                             && isequal(ishandle(varargin{2}), 1) ...
                             && (~isempty(strfind(varargin{1},[get(varargin{2}, 'Tag'), '_'])) || ...
                                    ~isempty(strfind(varargin{1}, '_CreateFcn'))) );
    catch
            result = false;
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the GUIDE function to get you started.

http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/guide.html

All of the features you have listed are available through this tool.  One of the most critical items in order to 'connect' you GUI features together is learn how to pass data between functions.  By default GUIDE has a function call back that contains a Matlab structure named "handles" (you can change this to whatever you want.  Try simply passing a few values between functions to get started.